# Modal Popup not displaying content

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I have a modal popup on a calendar which displays the DispForm.aspx page. Currently on some devices it shows as expected but it is also run within a program which takes IE and cuts parts off.

The modals here just continue to load and then load but display non of the content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("a[href*='TrimDispForm.aspx']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("onclick", "openDialog('" + $(this).text() + "','" + $(this).attr("href") + "')");
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
            $(this).removeAttr("target");
        });
    }, 900);
});

function openDialog(title, url) {
    var options = {
        title: "Calendar - " + title,
    autoSize:true,
        url: url
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Open the same link directly in IE on the same machine and it loads as expected. What settings may be required for a modal to function correctly in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue around this has been resolved.

The browser was encased in another program which was not picking up the correct values from the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and that was causing it not to correctly render.

By setting the BROWSER_EMULATION for the user rather than the device fixed the issue.